# Map View tiles not showing

Tags: android

I am integrating google maps in my app.in order to run app in actuall device i want a release key. i use these steps to generate release key 
1:right click project =>export =>create new keystore
2:right click project => export using existing keystore => give path of the keystore that i just created in step 1
3:sign up using my md5

when i paste the release key into my `mapView` not tiles were shown. i got this error

```
02-17 00:20:36.848: W/System.err(953): IOException processing: 26
02-17 00:20:36.848: W/System.err(953): java.io.IOException: Server returned: 3
02-17 00:20:36.867: W/System.err(953):  at android_maps_conflict_avoidance.com.google.googlenav.map.BaseTileRequest.readResponseData(BaseTileRequest.java:115)
02-17 00:20:36.867: W/System.err(953):  at android_maps_conflict_avoidance.com.google.googlenav.map.MapService$MapTileRequest.readResponseData(MapService.java:1473)
02-17 00:20:36.867: W/System.err(953):  at android_maps_conflict_avoidance.com.google.googlenav.datarequest.DataRequestDispatcher.processDataRequest(DataRequestDispatcher.java:1117)
02-17 00:20:36.867: W/System.err(953):  at android_maps_conflict_avoidance.com.google.googlenav.datarequest.DataRequestDispatcher.serviceRequests(DataRequestDispatcher.java:994)
02-17 00:20:36.876: W/System.err(953):  at android_maps_conflict_avoidance.com.google.googlenav.datarequest.DataRequestDispatcher$DispatcherServer.run(DataRequestDispatcher.java:1702)
02-17 00:20:36.876: W/System.err(953):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
02-17 00:20:37.546: W/System.err(953): IOException processing: 26



<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.locationmeter"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="5"
        android:targetSdkVersion="10" />

    <supports-screens
        android:anyDensity="true"
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:resizeable="true"
        android:smallScreens="true" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <supports-screens
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:smallScreens="true" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:debuggable="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.LocationMeter" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.locationmeter.ActivitySplash"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".ActivityMenu" >
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".ActivityCurrentLocation" >
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".ActivityLiveMap" >
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".ActivityPlacesTypes" >
        </activity>

        <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Did you add permissions to the manifest?

Comment: yes. debug key works but release key not

Answer (score 1):

I think it's getting an Exception in your 26th line. Please go through your code once again, otherwise, put it over here.

Do one thing also, try to generate an another key and use it.

Hope this may help you.

Comment: 26th line of my activity `private LocationManager locationManager;`i used to generate many times but same result